# Как выполнять программу дальше, если произошла ошибка?

Tags: php, dom

```
$htmlDoct = new DOMDocument();
$htmlDoct->loadHTMLFile($location);
$searchNode = $htmlDoc->getElementById($imgid);
$valueSrc = $searchNode->getAttribute('src');
```

Cделала программу, которая получает src фото по id, но если src не найдено то `$ searchNodet-> getAttribute ( 'src');` останавливает выполнение программы, как выполнять программу дальше если не найден src?

Comment: проверить что `$searchNode` не равно `null`, например.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверять значение, возвращаемое методами [`getElementById`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/domdocument.getelementbyid.php)

> **Возвращаемые значения**
>
> Возвращает объект DOMElement или **NULL, если элемент не найден**.

и [`getAttribute`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/domelement.getattribute.php)

> **Возвращаемые значения**
>
> Значение атрибута или **пустое значение, если атрибут с указанным именем name не найден**.

```
$htmlDoct = new DOMDocument();
$htmlDoct->loadHTMLFile($location);
$searchNode = $htmlDoc->getElementById($imgid);
if ($searchNode !== null) {
  // нашли элемент
  $valueSrc = $searchNode->getAttribute('src'); 
  if ($valueSrc !== "") {
    // нашли атрибут
  } else {
    // атрибут отсутствует
  }
} else {
  // элемент отсутствует
}
```